# Social Graph amount of friends of a node

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I’m trying to solve the following exercise. Where I have the following undirected graph. 
Where H is Hans, F is Finn etc.

[image]

So far, I’ve made two friendship chains of Hans friends from the graph above.

[image]

But if I then had to specify all 2 friends of Hans would it be **{Otto, Knud and Berge}** and not Finn as that would require 3 steps?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455796/algorithm-for-finding-t-friends-of-node