# Algorithm for finding t-friends of node

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

[image]

[image]

I have the following exercise where I have a social graph look below. From my understanding if **t = 2** and we have **p = H** then the result would be equal **O and B**.

Is this understanding correct?

[image]

Comment: Could you give the definition of what a `t-friend` is ?

Comment: I would assume that H has one 0-friend, and that is H itself.  H has two 1-friends, namely O and B.  H has one 2-friend which is K.  But as @m.raynal already commented, it depends on the definition of `t-friend`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Here you can ① post your code (as a [mcve]), ② describe what you observe it does (with which input), and ③ describe what you expect to observe instead.  This results in a clear question which can be answered.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about this.

Comment: @m.raynal Sorry that I forgot that crucial piece of information. I've now updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a breadth-first search from the origin point. When you enqueue a point, also enqueue the distance from the origin. Limit the distance to `t` by not enqueueing point with a distance more than `t`. The set of  visited nodes is the solution.

You visit each vertex at most once, you visit each edge at most once. Complexity is `O(E)`.

Comment: So you are saying the distance is the level you are going down the graph or distance is the counter for each node?

Meaning the result would be t = 2 outputs B, O and K?

Comment: This will be the shortest distance. There may be more than one chain with different length between two nodes.